# How to set equal margin to rows and columns in CSS grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have such container

```
    #container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(210px, 1fr));
    }
```

of such items

```
    .picture_tile{
        width:200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: relative;
        background: white;
        color: black;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

it adjusts nicely horizontally. It nicely adjusts while scaling my monitor, is it possible to apply space between the images to rows as well? I am total beginner to CSS. Is it possible to apply the same space that is changing between the items on vertical gap? When I scale my monitor and the items' horizontal gap is anything between 10-50px. Can the same change apply on vertical gap while changing horizontal size of my window? I hope it's understandable. I only want to have perfect grid with perfect gaps, everything same, but the content would be dynamic and behave like when display: grid is applied

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grid-gap: value` property on your `#container`

Comment: well, and how you set it dynamically so it copies horizontal spaces between the items?

Comment: @Jansindl3r suppose you set `grid-gap:20px`, it sets equal 20px `grid-row-gap` and `grid-column-gap`; you can set them separately too....

Comment: It has been a long search but I managed to do it. https://jansindl3r.github.io/renata/ (after 10secs of being on that page) hmm I don't even remember how I did it. 
But padding-top 100% keeps the div squarish. I will post a proper answer in case some other people want to do the same

Comment: Now the gaps are fixed, but I tried different approach where the squares stayed the same width and height and the gaps would change.